# Can I have a live matrix wallpaper on Ubuntu 13.04? How?

Tags: 13.04, desktop-background

I searched the web and found there is a live wallpaper option but it may only work for 12.04, and only has three options.

I want a live matrix wallpaper on my Ubuntu13.04.

Is this possible? If so how?

Thanks for the help! I'd really LOVE this customization!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to install a tool called xwinwrap, then you can run any screensaver as a background like this:
    xwinwrap -ni -argb -fs -s -st -sp -nf -b -- /usr/lib/xreensaver/glmatrix -window-id WID

Notes:
You may have to stop nautilus taking over you desktop. You can set this in gnome tweak tool under 'Desktop'. 
It is pretty resource heavy with some screensavers.